# HTML div display on the top of flash (flex-3) issue on Chrome & Firefox

Tags: apache-flex, google-chrome, firefox, jsf-1.2

I have a HTML div on the top of flash object(flex-3). Its coming in IE-8. But its not coming on Chrome/Firefox. Problem is that when I open developer tool of those two browser its coming.

So the problem is that **without developer tool its not appearing on the screen**.

I used Z-index, display:block, param name="wmode" value="opaque" as well.

```
<script>    
function setupDivDimensions(){
    var  bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var bodyW = bodyElement.clientWidth;
    var bodyH = bodyElement.clientHeight;
    document.getElementById('flexContainerMain').setAttribute("style","position:relative;width:"+bodyW+";height:"+bodyH);
    document.getElementById('flexContainerMain').style.width=bodyW;
    document.getElementById('flexContainerMain').style.height=bodyH;
    document.getElementById('uam_boxes').setAttribute("style","z-index:3;display:block;");
    document.getElementById('flexContainer').setAttribute("style","z-index:1;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;display:block;width:"+bodyW+";height:"+bodyH);
    document.getElementById('flexContainer').style.width=bodyW;
    document.getElementById('flexContainer').style.height=bodyH;
}

</script>

<body onload="setupDivDimensions();">
<input type="hidden" id="globalLogoutUrl" name="globalLogoutUrl"
    value="/logout/page/link/goes/here" />
<input type="hidden" id="appLogoutUrl" name="appLogoutUrl" value="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Logout" />

<f:verbatim>
    <div id="flexContainerMain">
    <div id="uam_boxes"></div>

    <div id="flexContainer"><Object id="flex" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%"
        height="100%" codebase="https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
        <param name="movie" value="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/flex/MyFlashPage.swf" />
        <embed src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/flex/MyFlashPage.swf" width="100%" height="100%" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <param name='flashVars'
            value='userName=<h:outputText value="#{USER_OBJECT_KEY.userName}"/>&selMenuId=<h:outputText value="#{menuController.selectedMenuItem.menuId}"/>&selMenuTitle=<h:outputText value="#{menuController.selectedMenuItem.title}"/>' />
    </object></div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:none">
    <form name="redirection" action="" method="post" width="0" height="0"><f:verbatim>
        <a style="margin-right:20px;" class="globalLinkBranding"
            onmouseover="isStatusAvail = false;window.status='Logout';return true" onmouseout="isStatusAvail = true;"
            id="uam_modal"> Logout </a>
    </form>
    </div>
</f:verbatim>

</body>
```

Comment: It might be helpful to show the HTML you're using. Using  "opaque" or "transparent" for the `wmode` param comes with some issues (affects performance, breaks accessibility, and can expose weird bugs in certain browsers...) but nothing as drastic as what you're describing. So there must be a solution to what you're seeing, it's just not obvious from the information you've provided so far.

Comment: @Sunil D: updated with HTML/JSF code above

Comment: You might look into using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your app. SWFObject is pretty much considered the industry standard way of embedding Flash apps. I have to admit, I'm not seeing anything wrong ... but I wonder if the code that is happening in your `setupDivDimensions()` function is part of the problem.

Comment: For example, you might refactor it so that the `<object>` and `<embed>` tags are created via SWFObject, and that you do that at the end of your `setupDivDimensions()` function. Note that the `<object>` and `<params>` tags are for IE, and the `<embed>` tag is for every other browser.